# Set Cell Background Color Not Working Properly On TreeView Gtk C#

Tags: c#, linux, gtk#, gtk2

Using **SetCellDataFunc** for modifying cell property at runtime.

**Requirement: Modify cell background colour for a particular column**

Want to modify cell colour of "**Item Quantit**y" Column

It modifies the colour of the cell of all columns.

this unexpected behaviour because enabled the only for one column.

Can you please help me with this

[image: Application output]

Please find snippet code

```
using System;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow : Gtk.Window
{
private Gtk.TreeView treeView;
private Gtk.ListStore listStore;

private Gtk.VBox ItemViewPad;
private Gtk.ScrolledWindow scrolledWindow;

public MainWindow() : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
{
    Build();

    ItemViewPad = new VBox();

    scrolledWindow = new ScrolledWindow();

    treeView = new TreeView();

    listStore = new ListStore(typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string));

    CellRendererText cellRendererText = new CellRendererText();
    TreeViewColumn treeViewColumnName = new TreeViewColumn();
    treeViewColumnName.Expand = true;
    treeViewColumnName.Title = "Item Name";
    treeViewColumnName.PackStart(cellRendererText, false);
    treeViewColumnName.AddAttribute(cellRendererText, "text", 0);

    TreeViewColumn treeViewColumnType = new TreeViewColumn();
    treeViewColumnType.Expand = true;
    treeViewColumnType.Title = "Item Type";
    treeViewColumnType.PackStart(cellRendererText, false);
    treeViewColumnType.AddAttribute(cellRendererText, "text", 1);

    TreeViewColumn treeViewColumnQuantity = new TreeViewColumn();
    treeViewColumnQuantity.Expand = true;
    treeViewColumnQuantity.Title = "Item Quantity";
    treeViewColumnQuantity.PackStart(cellRendererText, false);
    treeViewColumnQuantity.AddAttribute(cellRendererText, "text", 2);
    treeViewColumnQuantity.SetCellDataFunc(cellRendererText, new TreeCellDataFunc(OnChangedQuantity));

    treeView.AppendColumn(treeViewColumnName);
    treeView.AppendColumn(treeViewColumnType);
    treeView.AppendColumn(treeViewColumnQuantity);

    treeView.Model = listStore;

    scrolledWindow.Add(treeView);

    ItemViewPad.PackStart(scrolledWindow, true, true, 6);

    Add(ItemViewPad);
    if ((this.Child != null))
        this.Child.ShowAll();
    ShowAll();

    listStore.AppendValues(new object[] { "Pen", "10", "10" });
    listStore.AppendValues(new object[] { "Pencil", "20", "20" });
    listStore.AppendValues(new object[] { "ColorPen", "30", "30" });
}

private void OnChangedQuantity(TreeViewColumn tree_column, CellRenderer cell, TreeModel tree_model, TreeIter iter)
{
    string quantity = (string)tree_model.GetValue(iter, 2);
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(quantity))
    {
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(tree_column.Title);

    Gdk.Color color = cell.CellBackgroundGdk;

    if(string.Compare(quantity, "30") == 0)
    {
        color = new Gdk.Color(255, 0, 0);
    }
    else if (string.Compare(quantity, "20") == 0)
    {
        color = new Gdk.Color(0, 255, 0);
    }
    else if (string.Compare(quantity, "10") == 0)
    {
        color = new Gdk.Color(0, 0, 255);
    }

    cell.CellBackgroundGdk = color;
}

private void OnChangedType(TreeViewColumn tree_column, CellRenderer cell, TreeModel tree_model, TreeIter iter)
{
    string type = (string)tree_model.GetValue(iter, 1);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(type))
    {
        return;
    }

    Gdk.Color color = cell.CellBackgroundGdk;

    if (string.Compare(type, "30") == 0)
    {
        color = new Gdk.Color(0, 0, 255);
    }
    else if (string.Compare(type, "20") == 0)
    {
        color = new Gdk.Color(0, 255, 0);
    }
    else if (string.Compare(type, "10") == 0)
    {
        color = new Gdk.Color(255, 0, 0);
    }

    cell.CellBackgroundGdk = color;
}

private void OnChangedName(TreeViewColumn tree_column, CellRenderer cell, TreeModel tree_model, TreeIter iter)
{
    string name = (string)tree_model.GetValue(iter, 0);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        return;
    }
}

protected void OnDeleteEvent(object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
{
    Application.Quit();
    a.RetVal = true;
}
}

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.Init();
        MainWindow win = new MainWindow();
        win.Show();
        Application.Run();
    }
```

Comment: It could be to do with the fact that you have the same CellRenderText object used for all columns. Maybe try a different (new) CellRendererText for each column?

Comment: it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use different CellRendererText binding for each Column.

```
    CellRendererText cellRendererTextName = new CellRendererText();
    TreeViewColumn treeViewColumnName = new TreeViewColumn();
    treeViewColumnName.Expand = true;
    treeViewColumnName.Title = "Item Name";
    treeViewColumnName.PackStart(cellRendererTextName, false);
    treeViewColumnName.AddAttribute(cellRendererTextName, "text", 0);

    CellRendererText cellRendererTextType = new CellRendererText();
    TreeViewColumn treeViewColumnType = new TreeViewColumn();
    treeViewColumnType.Expand = true;
    treeViewColumnType.Title = "Item Type";
    treeViewColumnType.PackStart(cellRendererTextType, false);
    treeViewColumnType.AddAttribute(cellRendererTextType, "text", 1);
    treeViewColumnType.SetCellDataFunc(cellRendererTextType, new TreeCellDataFunc(OnChangedType));

    CellRendererText cellRendererTextQuantity = new CellRendererText();
    TreeViewColumn treeViewColumnQuantity = new TreeViewColumn();
    treeViewColumnQuantity.Expand = true;
    treeViewColumnQuantity.Title = "Item Quantity";
    treeViewColumnQuantity.PackStart(cellRendererTextQuantity, false);
    treeViewColumnQuantity.AddAttribute(cellRendererTextQuantity, "text", 2);
    treeViewColumnQuantity.SetCellDataFunc(cellRendererTextQuantity, new TreeCellDataFunc(OnChangedQuantity));
```